# Authenticate Blazor WebAssembly using multiple identity providers

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor-webassembly

I am learning Blazor WebAssembly and building a small project to be hosted as Static Web App in Azure.

The target framework is net5.0.

When the user clicks over 'login' hyperlink or button, a new page will display the names of some identity providers (Microsoft, Google, SackOverflow, etc.). Then the user will select one to log in.

I did it using just one identity provider (just Microsoft, just Google, etc.).

How can I use multiple identity providers in the same app ?

Someone can help me, please ?

Blazor WebAssembly App

TargetFramework: net5.0

Hosted as Static Web App in Azure

**Program.cs**

```
using Blazored.LocalStorage;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileProcApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args) {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

            builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options => {
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Clear();
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("openid");
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("offline_access");
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions);
            });
            
            builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options => {
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Clear();               
                builder.Configuration.Bind("Google", options.ProviderOptions);
            });


            builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<Services.Authentication>();

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Google": {
    "Authority": "https://accounts.google.com/",
    "ClientId": "1234567890123-45678901234567890123456789012345.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://lorem-ipsun-dolor-sit-amet.azurestaticapps.net/authentication/logout-callback",
    "RedirectUri": "https://lorem-ipsun-dolor-sit-amet.azurestaticapps.net/authentication/login-callback",
    "ResponseType": "token id_token"
  },
  "AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
    "ClientId": "12345678-9012-3456-7890-123456789012",
    "ValidateAuthority": true
  }
}
```

**LoginDisplay.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
@using System.Text.Json

@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject SignOutSessionStateManager SignOutManager

@inject Services.Authentication UserAuthentication

@inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService localStorage

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!

        <img src="img/UsrTeste.jpg" style="width:28px; cursor:pointer; " />
        <span style="cursor:pointer; ">usuario.teste@teste.com.br</span>

        <div>
            @System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(context.User.Identity, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true });
            @RegistraAutenticacao();
        </div>
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" @onclick="BeginSignOut">Log out</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a class="sign-in" href="authentication/register">Register</a>
        <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
    <Authorizing>
        <span>Autorizando</span>
    </Authorizing>
</AuthorizeView>


@code{
    private async Task BeginSignOut(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        await SignOutManager.SetSignOutState();
        Navigation.NavigateTo("authentication/logout");
    }
    private async Task RegistraAutenticacao() {
        await UserAuthentication.RegistraAutenticacao();
    }
}
```